# Grouping items in QGIS Layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer, layouts

At QGIS 3.12.3, I need to group the two items highlighted in this screenshot:

[image]

According to the [QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/composer_items/composer_items_options.html#grouping-items): *"To create a group of items, **select more than one** and press the Group button..."* [Emphasis added]

But how do I select more than one item?

Here's what I've tried:

In my example above, I select the first item by clicking on either one of the two, which highlights it.  I then ctrl-click the second item.  But that just *switches* the selection and highlights the second item; it is not *added* to the selection.  Same thing when I try shift-click.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to select the items from the layout itself and then go to the `main menu -> Item -> Group`, and it will group the items selected.

The following animation will make it clear on how to group items:

[image]